# Tableau Calculated Field COUNTD Single Value

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to create a Calculated Field which returns COUNTD if COUNTD is greater than 1 and returns the field value. So, if there is more than one Company then it will show the number but if only 1, then it will show the company name.

```
If [Company Count] > 1 then [Company Count] else [Company Name] END
```

I have tried this I either get an error "Cannot Mix Aggregate and Non-Aggregate comparisons or results in 'If' expressions.

Is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use LOD expression

```
Company Count= {Fixed :countd([company Name])}

companies= If [Company Count] > 1 then str([Company Count]) else [Company Name] END
```

Answer (score 1):

After some experimenting and further Googling I have found a solution.

```
if Min([Company Name]) = max([Company Name]) then 
MIN([Company Name]) 
else 
STR([Company Count]) + " Companies" 
END
```